# Exclude OU from search PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to exclude an OU (sub-OU) from a search with PowerShell.

This is my code:

```html
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=test,DC=test,DC=com' |
 
foreach {
 
$users=Get-ADUser -filter * -searchbase $_.distinguishedname -ResultPageSize 2000 -resultSetSize 500 -searchscope Onelevel | where-object enabled -eq true 
 
$total=($users | measure-object).count
 
New-Object psobject -Property @{
 
OU=$_.Name;
 
A=$Total
 
}
 
}
```

I'm a PowerShell beginner. Can you please help me to exclude an OU from the search results?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By adding an if statement:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=test,DC=test,DC=com' | foreach {

    if($_.distinguishedname -ne "OU=not,OU=that,OU=orgUnit,OU=test,DC=test,DC=com"){

        $users=Get-ADUser -filter * -searchbase $_.distinguishedname -ResultPageSize 2000 -resultSetSize 500 -searchscope Onelevel | where-object enabled -eq true 
        $total=($users | measure-object).count
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            OU=$_.Name;
            A=$Total
        }
    }
}
```